# Shutting down oracle database from c# using Oracle.DataAccess

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm running an Oracle 10g database and am currently writing an application in c# to interact with it.

I have written what I need to to connect to the database, and am able to query it to return a result. I started by logging in as SYSMAN, using the System.Data.OracleClient.But in order to shutdown and restart the database I need to be logged in with SYSDBA privileges (correct me if I'm wrong) As I couldn't do that using System.Data.OracleClient I'm now using the ODP, Oracle.DataAccess.

My problem is that I'm trying to run the command "Shutdown immediate" but I'm getting the error:

Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Any ideas on what I need to change, the following is the code I am using to execute the query.

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(
"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=smile)(PORT=1521)"+
"(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MOUTH.smile)));"+
"User id=SYSMAN;Password=thepassword;DBA PRIVILEGE=SYSDBA";

int value;
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("shutdown immediate", conn);
value = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I know it connects OK as I've queried the DB and got results, not sure that I definately have the SYSDBA privilege, and not sure how to check?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This article might be useful: http://docs.oracle.com/html/E15167_01/OracleDatabaseClass.htm#CHDFBHBH

Use the OracleDatabase.Shutdown method and pass the OracleDBShutdownMode.Immediate parameter